# Partial template member specialisation for arrays

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to have a template class for different data types:

```
template <typename TDataType>
class CBaseProperty : public CBasePropertyBase
```

now this class has a specialisation for arrays like this:

```
template <typename TDataType, u32 TSize>
class CBaseProperty<TDataType[TSize]> : public CBasePropertyBase
```

now i want to write a specialised version of specific member function for strings:

```
template <> b8 CBaseProperty<string>::setValue(const void* _pVal)
```

as soon as i try to specify this member for my partial specialisation of arrays for strings:

```
template <u32 _TSize> b8 CBaseProperty<string[TSize]>::setValue(const void* _pVal)
```

i get 3 errors:

> Error 1   error C3860: template argument list following class template
>   name must list parameters in the order used in template parameter list
>
> Error 2   error C2995: `b8 CBaseProperty<TDataType>::setValue(const void*)` : function template has already been defined
>
> Error 3   error C3855: `CBaseProperty<TDataType>`: template parameter `TDataType` is
>   incompatible with the declaration

What am i doing wrong? According to all my sources my syntax is correct for a partial member specialisation.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: can you show the definition of string? Is it an alias to a built in type or is it a class template? If its a class template you are using the wrong kind of brace [ rather than <

Comment: also what is u32? try using std::size_t instead of u32

Comment: @PorkyBrain:
Sorry, i forgot that:

    typedef unsigned int u32;

and my string is a std::string

Comment: @quantdev: I try to have a class that can hold data as either plain data or in array form: i wnat to be able to write: CBaseProperty<int> VarName; as well as CBaseProperty<int[4]> VarName; and i want to use different methods and data stored in two different template classes. For example the array class will contain an array access operator [].

Comment: @ThomasB.: You should not wantonly `typedef` types, especially when they have well known names.  Moreover, the name `u32` has baked in the assumption that the type will be 32 bits wide, which is not guaranteed for `unsigned int`.  The standard library actually provides types that do have such a guarantee, are well known, and cross-platform.  The one you seek is [`std::uint32_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint).  Lastly, if you're choosing a type for the size of something, you should always choose [`std::size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only specialize a single member function by providing **all template arguments** (you left the length as an argument), it would force you here to specify the array length.

So if you need a specialized version for arrays of strings, leaving the length as a parameter, you need a specialization of the class template for array of strings first.

As far as I understand your post, the solution can be reduced to the following minimal example :

```
template<class T>
class foo
{
    public:
    void tell() { cout << "general\n"; }
    void base() { cout << "ok"; }
};

template<class T, std::size_t N>
class foo<T[N]>
{
    public:
    void tell() { cout << "special arrays\n"; }
};

template<std::size_t N>
class foo<std::string[N]>
{
    public:
    void tell() { cout << "special string arrays\n"; }
};

template<>
void foo<std::string>::tell()
{
  cout << "string\n";   
}

int main()
{
  foo<std::string[2]> f;   
  f.tell();

  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

> special string arrays

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats what a wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <u32 _TSize> b8 CBaseProperty<string[TSize]>::setValue(const void* _pVal)
```

this is not valid code when string  is an alias for std::string because std::string is variable in length so you can specialize on its length at compile time

```
template <typename TDataType, u32 TSize>
class CBaseProperty<TDataType[TSize]> : public CBasePropertyBase
```

this could work but is risky because what type std::size_t is is implementation defined so if the type of your u32 (which you said in your comment is unsigned int) is not the same as std::size_t it may not match.

see live example: http://ideone.com/ZH4v6x

Comment: This template should be not used for different length strings, but instead for a class that holds and array of multiple strings like when i would write: string[5] MyStrings;

Comment: Your live example is exactly what i already did with my class itself. Now i want a version of the method which is called for strings as DataType. And i want this method to be different for the array and the not array class.